# Xcode: Distributing Apps per USB

Tags: iphone, xcode, certificate

I'm new to Swift Programming and I've created an app for my fathers company (for free of course) containing the prices he can make his clients. Now, everyone of the co-workers are supposed to also have this App on their iPhones. The Problem is, that we can't Upload it to the AppStore since my father doesn't want other companies to see the prices he can make.

How can I distribute this app just to the devices of my fathers co-workers?

And secondly: can I generate an App Certificate for apps that I'm loading from Xcode per USB?

I'm sorry for my bad english but thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options :

- Option 1: You create user and password in your apps - After you
  submit on app store and give user & password for who can use it.
- Option 2 : You can make app certificate - but you need their phone
  UDID and install direct on their phone (But when you update your app,
  you have to manual update all of their phone.

p/s: My English isn't well, either!